# Ignored constraint on iOs 7 working on ios 8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I've been struggling with this issue for hours.

I'm using a simple CollectionView which has a custom cell with custom nib file.
Also I set the size of the cell by doing this:

`- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return collectionView.frame.size;
}`

I'm just trying to center a subview in the cell and so far It's working great in iOs8, the view is centered and I even call `reloadData` in `viewWillTransitionToSize:` so the cell size updates when rotating.

The Result in iOs8
[image: The Result in iOs8]

But in iOs 7 it seems that the center constraint I added to the view is totally ignored.
Actually it's acting like he doesn't listen to the constraint once the cell size is changed, in the `collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Giving this unpleasant result:
[image]

Am I setting the constraints correctly? did I forget something like `layoutIfNeeded` or `needsUpdateConstraints` somewhere ?

Here you can download a simple tiny project that has my problem.
http://goo.gl/mBmI1H

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do answer myself,

Actually I solved the problem by removing the center constraints in interface builder and adding them in code like this :

```
[self addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:self.connectedContainer
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

I do not understand the -1 since this is a real issue, I'm using Xcode Version 6.0 (6A313).

I hope this will help someone having the same problem I did.

Comment: wow! so many hours of struggling with IB center constraints in collection cells and this answer fix it, thanks for sharing :)